# Secondary Menu display Primary Menu

Tags: menus

EDİT -----

Maybe it's being helpful. The problem is here:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('the_location'=>'primary')); ?>
```

İt must being

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary')); ?>
```

---

I am really angry because I am trying an 1 hour for this little problem and I found nothing. Firstly, I am newbie in Wordpress but I think I wasn't doing any error here. Anyway, I add the code below.

Header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('the_location'=>'primary')); ?>
```

İndex.php

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu(array('the_location'=>'secondary')); ?>
```

funcstions.php

```
function register_menu() {
add_theme_support('menus');

register_nav_menus( array(  
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation' ),  
  'secondary' => __('Secondary Navigation')  
) );

}

add_action('init','register_menu');
```

And wordpress panel screenshots:

[image]

Comment: So.... what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the code close, but incorrect. It is a spelling issue.

It should be:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'secondary')); ?>
```

Please note that in your array you are using `the_location` and not `theme_location`. I believe with your mistake the menu will default to the primary menu (though I haven't confirmed this).